# Access Denied error for enterprise Github account. error:14077419

Tags: git, github

I created a repository using a github enterprise account and when I try to push my code to remote repository and it gives following error.

```
fatal: unable to access '[The repository URL]': error:14077419:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert access denied
```

To bypass the firewall, I already added the `.gitconfig` file at the root of my user account folder.

Also, I download the Github Desktop application and it is successfully configured with my windows user account. From that application, I was able to browse the projects in the remote repository but can not clone a single one. It gives following error.

```
WARNING: 'git lfs clone' is deprecated and will not be updated
          with new flags from 'git clone'

'git clone' has been updated in upstream Git to have comparable
speeds to 'git lfs clone'.
Cloning into [my folder location]
fatal: unable to access '[repository URL]': schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_ILLEGAL_MESSAGE (0x80090326) - This error usually occurs when a fatal SSL/TLS alert is received (e.g. handshake failed). More detail may be available in the Windows System event log.
Error(s) during clone:
git clone failed: exit status 128
```

Can someone please address on this issue to me.